# commonly used practices for deploying package primarily composed of bash scripts

Tags: c++, deployment, unix, bash

I am working on a tool that primarily uses `bash` scripts and `C++` code.

Generally I have experience with basic tools written in `C` and `C++` in which we can have a build system like `./configure; make; make install` in which we can simply install the libs and bins to the locations provided to third parties like `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/bin`.

What I don't know is what to do with scripts. Like what are the commonly used practices to deploy software with many bash scripts? Where do I store them on target machine?

Answer (score 4):

> Like what are the best practices to deploy software with many bash scripts?

Given you refer to `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/bin`, I'm assuming you're on some kind of Unix-ish machine - there, the answer is simple: use the OS's package manager. Build a .deb/.rpm or whatever and use the infrastructure which already exists.

Comment: Yea what you say is completely sensible. But that would require doing it for all pkg managers(yum, apt, macports, etc etc) that are being used on that respective OS. As my software is portable over almost all *nix, a simpler solution right now would be to have a simple build from source. My point was that like `/usr/local/*` directory structure would work on almost all *nix OS I know, is their something like that for my scenario?

Comment: At this point, you probably need to read [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing).

Comment: Well in that case maybe I misunderstood the rules of this site. I had read the tour of this site and it said "ask about, software development methods and practices" maybe that's not for best practices. Ok thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The trouble is not "practices" but "best". It's fine to ask about practices, but when you start asking what's "best" it rapidly becomes a personal thing - what I regard as best may not be what you regard as best, because you have different constraints from me.

Comment: Thanks. Have edited my question a bit. Maybe it no longer opinion based.

Comment: Note that, this answer is also convenient if your scripts or lbs have dependencies which also depends on the platform. For example, you might have some troubles deploying shells in Alpine distros when using Java commands as dependencies. Those problems aren't if you deploy in Oracle Linux. So seems convenient to package and distribute your shells and binaries via the OS package manager. I would even go further and say it could be interesting to publish your own public repository

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally (the slackware way) the userland scripts would exist in /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/sbin along with any binaries.  By convention, it's reserved for local administrator/software, so you're not going to clobber anything in /usr/local that you didn't mean to put there.

If you're releasing a binary package though, those normally exist with whatever structure they wish in '/opt' and add their userland executables and scripts to the path through the profile system.

Either way works, but /usr/local/s?bin is my preferred option as every profile system since the dawn of time automatically adds it to the path if there's an executable there; rather than having to add an extra configuration file and worrying about where it goes in what distro.